# How to upload image file to Stripe from Amazon S3 using Laravel 5.5 and Intervention Image

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-connect, intervention

Laravel 5.5 app. I need to retrieve images of driver's licenses from Amazon S3 (already working) and then upload it to Stripe using their api for identity verification (not working).

[Stripe's documents](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification-api#uploading-a-file) give this example:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY);
\Stripe\FileUpload::create(
    array(
        "purpose" => "identity_document",
        "file" => fopen('/path/to/a/file.jpg', 'r')
    ),
    array("stripe_account" => CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID)
);
```

However, I am not retrieving my files using `fopen()`.
When I retrieve my image from Amazon S3 (using my own custom methods), I end up with an instance of `Intervention\Image` -- essentially, `Image::make($imageFromS3)` -- and I don't know how to convert this to the equivalent of the call to `fopen('/path/to/a/file.jpg', 'r')`. I have tried the following:

```
$image->stream()

$image->stream()->__toString()

$image->stream('data-url')

$image->stream('data-url')->__toString()
```

I have also tried skipping intervention image and just using Laravel's storage retrieval, for example:

```
$image = Storage::disk('s3')->get('path/to/file.jpg');
```

All of these approaches result in getting an `Invalid hash` exception from Stripe.

What is the proper way to get a file from S3 and convert it to the equivalent of the `fopen()` call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file on S3 is public, you could just pass the URL to Stripe:

```
\Stripe\FileUpload::create(
    array(
        "purpose" => "identity_document",
        "file" => fopen(Storage::disk('s3')->url($file)),
    ),
    array("stripe_account" => CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID)
);
```

Note that this requires `allow_url_fopen` to be turned on in your `php.ini` file.

If not, then you could grab the file from S3 first, write it to a temporary file, and then use the `fopen()` method that the Stripe documentation speaks of:

```
// Retrieve file from S3...
$image = Storage::disk('s3')->get($file);

// Create temporary file with image content...
$tmp = tmpfile();
fwrite($tmp, $image);

// Reset file pointer to first byte so that we can read from it from the beginning...
fseek($tmp, 0);

// Upload temporary file to S3...
\Stripe\FileUpload::create(
    array(
        "purpose" => "identity_document",
        "file" => $tmp
    ),
    array("stripe_account" => CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID)
);

// Close temporary file and remove it...
fclose($tmp);
```

See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php for more information.