# Only plainfile resource streams are supported

Tags: php, laravel-5, basic-authentication

I am trying to upload identity document to stripe,

I have basic authorization in my server as well, here is code

```
$b64 = base64_encode("$username:$password");
$auth = "Authorization: Basic $b64";
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => "GET",
        'header' => $auth,
        'user_agent' => 'bob',
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$fp = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);
```

I have following code for uploading file to stripe

```
 \Stripe\FileUpload::create(
 array(
 "purpose" => "identity_document",
 "file" => $fp
 )
 );
```

but when i am trying to open file it is giving me following error

```
Api in ApiRequestor.php line 249:
Only plainfile resource streams are supported
in ApiRequestor.php line 249
at ApiRequestor->_processResourceParam(resource, true) in ApiRequestor.php line 210
at ApiRequestor->_requestRaw('post', '/v1/files', array('purpose' => 'identity_document', 'file' => resource), array()) in ApiRequestor.php line 64
at ApiRequestor->request('post', '/v1/files', array('purpose' => 'identity_document', 'file' => resource), array()) in ApiResource.php line 119
at ApiResource::_staticRequest('post', '/v1/files', array('purpose' => 'identity_document', 'file' => resource), null) in ApiResource.php line 158
at ApiResource::_create(array('purpose' => 'identity_document', 'file' => resource), null) in FileUpload.php line 49
at FileUpload::create(array('purpose' => 'identity_document', 'file' => resource)) in ProfileController.php line 959
```

Comment: The `$fp` variable needs to point to a local file, not remote URL.

Comment: this $url variable is directing to image url of server what i uploaded

Comment: That's exactly what Jiri is trying to explain. It needs a **local file system** path, not a URL.

Comment: it's laravel project, I was previously doing it like this 
fopen('profiles/xxx.png','r')
Profile is in public folder of laravel 
In this case it was saying couldn't open file, unable to connect to stripe.
when i ask stripe support they said we need absolute path rather than relative path

Comment: yes, it was the issue in path, by adding local path, public_path() . '/profiles/' in laravel project, it fixed the issue

Comment: @JirkaHrazdil, I just heve tested with ```fopen()```, it worked with ```url```. According to this post ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48954499/how-to-upload-image-file-to-stripe-from-amazon-s3-using-laravel-5-5-and-interven```, may be because ```allow_url_fopen ``` in your ```php.ini``` is not enabled.